# Defining an object of a subclass

Tags: c++, class, subclass

I am trying to construct a class with three subclasses, and then creating an object of these subclasses. This is what I am doing so far,

```
  class Car{
       class Red{
           public:
              ...    //functions
        };
        class Blue{
           public:
              ...    //functions
        };
        class Red{
           public:
              ...    //functions
        };
    };
```

I am having trouble creating an object of the class red. I tried doing this:
       Car*redCar;
       redCar = new Red;

But it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably meant to inherit from it: class Red : Car

Answer (score 2):

```
Car::Red redCar;
```

Assuming that Red is public.

Get a book on C++!